# Cannot extract and import CSV from ZIP in website to Google Sheets (App Scripts) with Basic Auth

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets, basic-authentication

I'm trying to get a CSV that is zipped in a URL, which needs basic auth. I can't get to do it. I get a syntax error on 'files' argument.  This is what I tried:

```js
function importdatastreamcsv() {
  
  var user = 'user';
  var pw = 'pass';

  var csvUrl = 'https://example.com/api/datastream/download/58350?tableIds=67595&usePreferences=false';
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl,{headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pw, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)}});
  var files = Utilities.unzip(csvContent)[0]; //syntax error on the argument! :(
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(files.getDataAsString());
 

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  sheet.setValues(csvData);

  
}
```

Looking for other alternatives, I noticed that is possible to pull the data in html table (not zip-csv format), so I wrote another script. It kind of worked, but all the information is in plain html and stored in only one cell, so it's almost impossible to read... here is the code:

```js
function importdatastreamhtml() {
  
  var user = 'user';
  var pw = 'pass';
  var csvUrl = 'https://example.com/api/datastream/download/58350?tableIds=67595&usePreferences=false&format=web'; 
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl,{headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pw, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8)}});
  var html = csvContent.getContentText();
 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1);
  sheet.setValue(html);


}
```

I need to have at least one of these two running correctly. What can I be missing here?

The output should be a simple table.

Many thanks,

César

Comment: Don't you need to iterate over each file in order to read the data inside it? Or should the getDataAsString() do this automatically?

Comment: I don't really know. I'm new to this. It's only one file so I don't see why I should iterate. Thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure what the unzip function returns. I assumed it returned several files since you called your variable "files". If the function returns an array of files, you need to iterate over it, even if there is only one file in the array. If not, then there is something else going wrong :/